# Don't allow a setter in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I've started looking into Groovy, and I've some mixed feelings about how class arguments are defined. By default, they include getter and setter, but what if I don't want to have a setter? What is the way to restrict to only allowing to get a value of a property? In C# it can be done like this:

```
public double Hours
{
    get { return seconds / 3600; }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 7):

If you declare the property as `final`, a setter won't be created.

Or, if you declare your own private/protected setter, then a public one won't be created.

So, as in your example:

```
Integer hours
private void setHours(Integer hours) {}
```

Or:

```
final Integer hours
```

Comment: Could I still change it's value? In some method or something.

Comment: So long as it's not final. Or look at the immutable annotation and copyWith

Comment: First option doesn't actually work even with Groovy v4.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3010 .  No way to allow the class itself to change the field value internally but not provide a public setter.  I guess work-around is to throw inside the setter instead of having an empty body.  Even if you created a private field and a getter method, Groovy still allows it to be set publicly.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to Metaprogramming feature of Groovy. In this case overrides
`setProperty(String name, Object value)` method to intercept the setter calls and trow exception instead.

```
class A {
    String a
    String b

    void setProperty(String name, Object value){
        throw new IllegalAccessError()
    }
}
```

This also works with getter as well by override `def getProperty(String name)`.

Answer (score -1):

In `groovy` once field is created, it will be by default `public` , setter and getter will be created.

So You can declare your own setter or getter and specify the access level, in this case, the default one will not be created.

example :

```
 private void setHours(Integer hours) {
    seconds * 3600
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct. By default all fields in groovy are public and not private.

Comment: @Biskit1943 yes that correct I just fix the text, thanks

Comment: Just want to point out here, without explicitly indicating public/private on the field, Groovy will default to `private` but it also creates public getter and setter for it. And when = assignment operator is used, Grovvy automatically call the setter to set the value. So, it looks like it's public but it's not. [ref](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties)